# Is the orthogonal spacing of dq axis of AC motor with respect to electrical or mechanical angle?

Tags: electric-machine, pmsm, synchronous-motor

In FOC of AC machines, we try to align the stator flux to Q axis and maximize the value. The idea behind this logic is when rotor flux and stator flux are orthogonal, we generate max flux. But is the dq axis orthogonality with respect to electrical or mechanical angle?

An extension to the above question: In case of a 8 pole pair machine, I think the angle per pole (three phase) in stator is 45 deg (360/8). If dq is spaced orthogonal electrically does it mean that d and q axis are compressed between the 11.25(45* 90/360) deg in mechanical angle?

Btw, my picture of ac motor is that there are 8 repetitive segments of ABC phase in the stator and each segment corresponds to a magnetic pole. Each segment is complete electrically by 360 deg.

Comment: Should be electrical. And yes, compressed.

Comment: @DKNguyen: shouldn't stator and rotor field be seperated spatially by 90 degrees for max torque? If fields are compressed then it means we never touch max torque

Comment: I don't understand dq enough to answer your question. What I do know is dq is a method to keep track of the three electrical phasors with two phasors.

Comment: "shouldn't stator and rotor field be seperated spatially by 90 degrees for max torque" ... yes : 90 electrical degrees. (Otherwise your 8 pole motor cannot generate torque at all because D and Q are in phase!)